# create google drive upload ability

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I create a little web system, written on PHP. Now we want to allow our clients to access out little system. On each job, they must upload one or more files (100-200 mb max size per file). Till now, i upload them via PHP component to server, but we have a lot of trouble with our ISP, and i decide to use free Google drive account. So, i read tutorials, but i can not understand clearly:

**Is there a way to upload file from client browser directly to Google drive, without upload to our server first? As far as I see, i can use php library to operate with my Google drive and upload files, but - unfortunately - files must be on out server first, which is my big problem.**

Big thanks in advance for every one which can help us.

Answer (score 1):

Direct upload from javascript to Drive is very easy. Check out the Drive Picker at https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/ which does everything for you.

Comment: Thank you. On examples that I try, i see that file was uploaded to drive account of user, not to my drive account - which is not suitable for me, but i suppose that i found the right settings.

Comment: If you want to upload to an application account, you'll need to use a Service Account. You'll need to think carefully what permissions you grant to a Javascript client that can write directly to your account. You mighth want to consider creating a small AppEngine project to act as an upload proxy.

Comment: Thank you @pinoyyd. I'll try to find some additional info and guides about your proposes.